# Standard error of estimates of covariance parameterized in tems of cholesky

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, covariance, standard-error, numerics

In unconstrained optimization, covariance matrix $C$ is parameterized in terms of its Cholesky ($C=LL^\prime)$. In other words, the parameter vector $\theta$ involves elements of the lower triangular matrix $L$.  Derivative of $-2LL$ with respect to $\theta$ is computed exactly. Hessian at the final-iteration is computed numerically (central difference).  Analytic derivatives of $C$ with respect to $L$ are also available (Jacobian?).  The goal is to compute variance of elements of computed covariance $var(C_{ii})$ and $var(C_{ij})$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you just take the diagonal elements of the Cholesky decomposition as your standard errors?

Comment: @Mike I believe that the nonzero entries of $L$ are *parameters* in this model. ML will produce a variance-covariance matrix for the entries of $L$; the problem is to use *that* to obtain a variance-covariance matrix for the nonlinear transformation thereof given by $L'L$.

Comment: If you have control over the software, why not modify it to perform a numerical calculation of the Hessian with respect to $C$ rather than w.r.t. $L$? If you cannot modify it but you can use it to compute the log likelihood at arbitrary values of $L$, you can still numerically estimate the Hessian.  This approach might be more accurate than other methods, such as the [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Note).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Partial derivatives of $-2LL$ with respect to $C_{ij}$ are computed at some point, so your approach is feasible.